# jupyter notebook, deeplearning, "homework" ругается на свои переменные

Tags: python

делаю задания в которых нужно дописывать код, но питон жалуется на то что якобы переменная не определенна,жалуется на ту переменную  которую добавил  "преподаватель" 
не могу ничего сделать уже и ядро кернел перепускал и задание заново начинал, мб есть айдии?

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: propagate

def propagate(w, b, X, Y):
    """
    Implement the cost function and its gradient for the propagation explained above

    Arguments:
    w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
    b -- bias, a scalar
    X -- data of size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
    Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if non-cat, 1 if cat) of size (1, number of examples)

    Return:
    cost -- negative log-likelihood cost for logistic regression
    dw -- gradient of the loss with respect to w, thus same shape as w
    db -- gradient of the loss with respect to b, thus same shape as b

    Tips:
    - Write your code step by step for the propagation. np.log(), np.dot()
    """

    m = X.shape[1]

    # FORWARD PROPAGATION (FROM X TO COST)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T, X) + b)                                   # compute activation
    cost = -1/m(np.dot(Y, np.log(a).T + np.dot(1 - Y, np.log(1 - a).T))                               # compute cost
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # BACKWARD PROPAGATION (TO FIND GRAD)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    dw = 1 / m * np.dot(X,(a - Y ).T)
    db = 1 / m * np.sum(a - Y)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
    assert(db.dtype == float)
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    assert(cost.shape == ())

    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}

    return grads, cost


w, b, X, Y = np.array([[1.],[2.]]), 2., np.array([[1.,2.,-1.],[3.,4.,-3.2]]), np.array([[1,0,1]])
grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)
print ("dw = " + str(grads["dw"]))
print ("db = " + str(grads["db"]))
print ("cost = " + str(cost))
```

```
 File "<ipython-input-28-e73d2c869dcb>", line 32
    dw = 1 / m * np.dot(X,(a - Y ).T)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: мне кажется, или в предыдущей строке (`cost = -1/m(np.dot(Y, np.log(a).T...`) не хватает скобки?

Answer (score 0):

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: propagate

def propagate(w, b, X, Y):
    """
    Implement the cost function and its gradient for the propagation explained above

    Arguments:
    w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
    b -- bias, a scalar
    X -- data of size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
    Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if non-cat, 1 if cat) of size (1, number of examples)

    Return:
    cost -- negative log-likelihood cost for logistic regression
    dw -- gradient of the loss with respect to w, thus same shape as w
    db -- gradient of the loss with respect to b, thus same shape as b

    Tips:
    - Write your code step by step for the propagation
    """

    m = X.shape[1]

    # FORWARD PROPAGATION (FROM X TO COST)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T, X) + b)  # compute activation
    cost = (- 1 / m) * np.sum(Y * np.log(A) + (1 - Y) * (np.log(1 - A)))  # compute cost
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # BACKWARD PROPAGATION (TO FIND GRAD)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    dw = (1 / m) * np.dot(X, (A - Y).T)
    db = (1 / m) * np.sum(A - Y)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
    assert(db.dtype == float)
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    assert(cost.shape == ())

    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}

    return grads, cost
```

нашел решение, не правильно был написан код из за чего питон думал что ошибка в синтаксисе